# SMB and AFP work for guest and Administrator but not other users

Tags: macos, smb, file-sharing, afp, kerberos

I'm having a problem getting file sharing to work between my MBPr and Mac Mini, here's a history of what I've tried:

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) running El Cap 10.11.1 (15B42) and recently acquired a Mac mini Server (Mid 2011) from my Aunty that was running an ancient version of OSX (and Server) that I upgraded to El Cap 10.11.1 (15B42). (probably irrelevant: The server came with an administrator account for my Aunty in her name that I haven't gotten rid of)

After upgrading I created a new account for myself (Derwent) from the administrator account with (Admin access, local authentication) and signed in with my Apple ID, then enabled SMB and AFP File Sharing for all accounts, ensuring my account, Derwent had access to a folder called Movies.

I could access this share remotely using SMB and AFP with the guest account, and with the administrator account, using terminal and Finder but no matter what I did, I couldn't access it using Derwent. I could also access my MBPr from my mini using Guest, Administrator and local authentication just fine.

I created a new standard account test with the password test, so that I was sure that I was getting the password correct, (this account was not signed in to any apple ID) and still it wouldn't work.

Here are some dumps of my console with different access methods.

**Browsing to the share in Finder directly, and using "Connect as"**

Get error message: `Access to your account on the server “minimac” has been denied.`

Console dump on server end:

```
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: Got a canonicalize request for a LKDC realm from local-ipc
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: LKDC referral to the real LKDC realm name
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:24:53 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: REQ-ENC-PA-REP
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: SRP announcing message of size 52
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: Need to use PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP/PA-PK-AS-REQ
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:24:53 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: SRP, REQ-ENC-PA-REP, FX-COOKIE
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: SRP step 1
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: ccsrp server start for user: test
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: FAST factor needs more preauth data, feed it
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:24:53 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: SRP, REQ-ENC-PA-REP, FX-COOKIE
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: SRP step 2
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: SRP pre-authentication succeeded -- test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, des3-cbc-sha1, arcfour-hmac-md5, using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96/aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: Requested flags: canonicalize
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: Client uses FAST
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: FAST strengthen reply key with strengthen-key
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: TGS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for cifs/localhost@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D [canonicalize]
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac kdc[232]: FAST armor protection
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac smbd[1409]: check_account - [7]:[permission denied] pam_acct_mgmt 
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: label: default
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]:   dbname: od:/Local/Default
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]:   mkey_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/m-key
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]:   acl_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/kadmind.acl
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: netr probe 0
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: od failed with -1561745588 proto=ntlmv2
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: user=MINIMAC\test
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request kdc: ok user=MINIMAC\test proto=ntlmv2 flags: ENC_128, NEG_VERSION, NEG_TARGET_INFO, NEG_NTLM, NEG_TARGET, NEG_UNICODE
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac smbd[1409]: check_account - [7]:[permission denied] pam_acct_mgmt 
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: od failed with -1561745588 proto=ntlmv2
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request: user=MINIMAC\test
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac digest-service[1419]: digest-request kdc: ok user=MINIMAC\test proto=ntlmv2 flags: ENC_128, NEG_VERSION, NEG_TARGET_INFO, NEG_NTLM, NEG_TARGET, NEG_UNICODE
Dec  1 00:24:53 minimac smbd[1409]: check_account - [7]:[permission denied] pam_acct_mgmt
```

**using Finder, afp://test:test@minimac.local/Movies**

```
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: Got a canonicalize request for a LKDC realm from local-ipc
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: LKDC referral to the real LKDC realm name
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:12:15 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: REQ-ENC-PA-REP
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: SRP announcing message of size 52
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: Need to use PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP/PA-PK-AS-REQ
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:12:15 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: SRP, REQ-ENC-PA-REP, FX-COOKIE
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: SRP step 1
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: ccsrp server start for user: test
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: FAST factor needs more preauth data, feed it
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:12:15 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: SRP, REQ-ENC-PA-REP, FX-COOKIE
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: SRP step 2
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: SRP pre-authentication succeeded -- test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, des3-cbc-sha1, arcfour-hmac-md5, using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96/aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: Requested flags: canonicalize
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: Client uses FAST
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: FAST strengthen reply key with strengthen-key
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: TGS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for afpserver/localhost@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D [canonicalize]
Dec  1 00:12:15 minimac kdc[232]: FAST armor protection
Dec  1 00:12:19 minimac WindowServer[185]: send_datagram_available_ping: pid 534 failed to act on a ping it dequeued before timing out.
```

**Using Finder, smb://test:test@minimac.local/Movies**

```
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: label: default
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]:   dbname: od:/Local/Default
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]:   mkey_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/m-key
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]:   acl_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/kadmind.acl
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: netr probe 0
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: Got a canonicalize request for a LKDC realm from local-ipc
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: LKDC referral to the real LKDC realm name
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:18:05 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: REQ-ENC-PA-REP
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: SRP announcing message of size 52
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: Need to use PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP/PA-PK-AS-REQ
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:18:05 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: SRP, REQ-ENC-PA-REP, FX-COOKIE
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: SRP step 1
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: ccsrp server start for user: test
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: FAST factor needs more preauth data, feed it
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:18:05 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: SRP, REQ-ENC-PA-REP, FX-COOKIE
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: SRP step 2
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: SRP pre-authentication succeeded -- test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, des3-cbc-sha1, arcfour-hmac-md5, using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96/aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: Requested flags: canonicalize
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: Client uses FAST
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: FAST strengthen reply key with strengthen-key
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: TGS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for cifs/localhost@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D [canonicalize]
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac kdc[232]: FAST armor protection
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac smbd[1366]: check_account - [7]:[permission denied] pam_acct_mgmt 
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: od failed with -1561745588 proto=ntlmv2
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: user=MINIMAC\test
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request kdc: ok user=MINIMAC\test proto=ntlmv2 flags: ENC_128, NEG_VERSION, NEG_TARGET_INFO, NEG_NTLM, NEG_TARGET, NEG_UNICODE
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac smbd[1366]: check_account - [7]:[permission denied] pam_acct_mgmt 
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: od failed with -1561745588 proto=ntlmv2
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request: user=MINIMAC\test
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac digest-service[1388]: digest-request kdc: ok user=MINIMAC\test proto=ntlmv2 flags: ENC_128, NEG_VERSION, NEG_TARGET_INFO, NEG_NTLM, NEG_TARGET, NEG_UNICODE
Dec  1 00:18:05 minimac smbd[1366]: check_account - [7]:[permission denied] pam_acct_mgmt 
Dec  1 00:18:08 minimac WindowServer[185]: send_datagram_available_ping: pid 534 failed to act on a ping it dequeued before timing out.
```

**Using Finder, cifs://test:test@minimac.local/Movies**

```
Dec  1 00:31:20 minimac kdc[232]: Got a canonicalize request for a LKDC realm from local-ipc
Dec  1 00:31:20 minimac kdc[232]: LKDC referral to the real LKDC realm name
Dec  1 00:31:20 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:31:20 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:31:20 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: REQ-ENC-PA-REP
Dec  1 00:31:20 minimac kdc[232]: SRP announcing message of size 52
Dec  1 00:31:20 minimac kdc[232]: Need to use PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP/PA-PK-AS-REQ
Dec  1 00:31:20 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:31:20 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:31:20 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: SRP, REQ-ENC-PA-REP, FX-COOKIE
Dec  1 00:31:20 minimac kdc[232]: SRP step 1
Dec  1 00:31:20 minimac kdc[232]: ccsrp server start for user: test
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac kdc[232]: FAST factor needs more preauth data, feed it
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:31:21 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: SRP, REQ-ENC-PA-REP, FX-COOKIE
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac kdc[232]: SRP step 2
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac kdc[232]: SRP pre-authentication succeeded -- test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac kdc[232]: Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, des3-cbc-sha1, arcfour-hmac-md5, using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96/aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac kdc[232]: Requested flags: canonicalize
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac kdc[232]: Client uses FAST
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac kdc[232]: FAST strengthen reply key with strengthen-key
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac kdc[232]: TGS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for cifs/localhost@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D [canonicalize]
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac kdc[232]: FAST armor protection
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac smbd[1453]: check_account - [7]:[permission denied] pam_acct_mgmt 
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: label: default
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]:   dbname: od:/Local/Default
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]:   mkey_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/m-key
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]:   acl_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/kadmind.acl
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: netr probe 0
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: od failed with -1561745588 proto=ntlmv2
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: user=MINIMAC\test
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request kdc: ok user=MINIMAC\test proto=ntlmv2 flags: ENC_128, NEG_VERSION, NEG_TARGET_INFO, NEG_NTLM, NEG_TARGET, NEG_UNICODE
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac smbd[1453]: check_account - [7]:[permission denied] pam_acct_mgmt 
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: od failed with -1561745588 proto=ntlmv2
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: user=MINIMAC\test
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request kdc: ok user=MINIMAC\test proto=ntlmv2 flags: ENC_128, NEG_VERSION, NEG_TARGET_INFO, NEG_NTLM, NEG_TARGET, NEG_UNICODE
Dec  1 00:31:21 minimac smbd[1453]: check_account - [7]:[permission denied] pam_acct_mgmt 
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: Got a canonicalize request for a LKDC realm from local-ipc
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: LKDC referral to the real LKDC realm name
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:31:49 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: REQ-ENC-PA-REP
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: SRP announcing message of size 52
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: Need to use PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP/PA-PK-AS-REQ
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:31:49 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: SRP, REQ-ENC-PA-REP, FX-COOKIE
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: SRP step 1
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: ccsrp server start for user: test
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: FAST factor needs more preauth data, feed it
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: AS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for krbtgt/LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:31:49 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: Client sent patypes: SRP, REQ-ENC-PA-REP, FX-COOKIE
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: SRP step 2
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: SRP pre-authentication succeeded -- test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, des3-cbc-sha1, arcfour-hmac-md5, using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96/aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: Requested flags: canonicalize
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: Client uses FAST
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: FAST strengthen reply key with strengthen-key
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: TGS-REQ test@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D from local-ipc for cifs/localhost@LKDC:SHA1.861AE3F013165CCB522112A9BD16DAE8ED59CC1D [canonicalize]
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac kdc[232]: FAST armor protection
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac smbd[1453]: check_account - [7]:[permission denied] pam_acct_mgmt 
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: od failed with -1561745588 proto=ntlmv2
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: user=MINIMAC\test
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request kdc: ok user=MINIMAC\test proto=ntlmv2 flags: ENC_128, NEG_VERSION, NEG_TARGET_INFO, NEG_NTLM, NEG_TARGET, NEG_UNICODE
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac smbd[1453]: check_account - [7]:[permission denied] pam_acct_mgmt 
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init request
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: init return domain: MINIMAC server: MINIMAC indomain was: <NULL>
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: uid=0
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: od failed with -1561745588 proto=ntlmv2
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request: user=MINIMAC\test
Dec  1 00:31:49 minimac digest-service[1454]: digest-request kdc: ok user=MINIMAC\test proto=ntlmv2 flags: ENC_128, NEG_VERSION, NEG_TARGET_INFO, NEG_NTLM, NEG_TARGET, NEG_UNICODE
Dec  1 00:31:50 minimac smbd[1453]: check_account - [7]:[permission denied] pam_acct_mgmt
```

I don't really understand these messages but hopefully someone with more experience will.

**Edit for clarification:**

```
account name , privileges, appleID           , machine
======================================================
derwent      , Admin     , derwent           , minimac
administrator, Admin     , -                 , minimac
test         , Standard  , -                 , minimac
jacq(deleted), Admin     , jacq              , minimac
derwent      , Admin     , derwent           , ich    


machine, share , user    , access      
======================================
minimac, Movies, derwent , read & write
minimac, Movies, test    , read only   
minimac, Movies, Everyone, read only
```

Comment: Would you mind adding additional information to your question? Which accounts are related to your Apple ID? All three or four accounts (Derwent, LocalAdmin, test) and LocalAdmin (macmini) = LocalAdmin (macbookpro) or only Derwent? Please clarify how all accounts are setup with a list!

Comment: Hey @klanomath thanks for looking at the question. The mac mini was inherited from my aunty, so the Administrator account is in her apple ID (she gave me the password for it) and I created a new account for Derwent. I think I put my own apple ID in there, then when I was trying to get SMB working I created the test account and didn't assign it an apple ID (i think) is there a command that I can run to give you the most accurate information?

Comment: I don't know of any command. The best thing are two lists: accountname - privileges (admin/standard/guest) - AppleID (yes/no and AppleID1 or Apple ID2) - machine/ machine - share - access rights (which account is allowed to access/which account is successful to access). It's a bit unclear in your question.

Comment: Please remove your email address. I only need appleid_me or appleid_other

Comment: ok will do, is there any other info i can give you that will help?

Answer (score 3):

Check if the `SMB-ACL` group (`com.apple.access_smb`) includes the affected users or one of their groups. This group is a system group that is hidden by default in the Groups view of the Server app (show them using "Show system accounts" in the context menu).

See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/441234/1931) for Monterey.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, in my case it was definitely the missing entry in the SMB Access List Group. Technically, when you select `Options...` and then add a user to the SMB-List there, it should automatically add that to the SMB Access List Group. But in my case it didn't. When I opened the "Groups" in "Directory Editor" of the `Directory Utility` and checked for SMB, I saw that the user in question was not listed there.

After adding the user to the group, it worked flawlessly.