# Basic File Sharing from Mac to Mac not working when connecting as guest - "Connection Failed"

Tags: network, sharing, smb, ventura

**Update 2/9/2023:**

It seems to be a macOS Ventura issue. A similar problem can be found here:

- [Apple Community: Cannot Connect to macOS Ventura on LAN](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254443579?answerId=258640862022#258640862022)
- [AppleInsider: Bug in macOS Ventura is breaking some networks](https://appleinsider.com/articles/23/02/03/bug-in-macos-ventura-is-breaking-some-networks).

I tried sharing files from a Big Sur with Guest access enabled. I connected to the Big Sur from a Ventura Mac and it works fine.

**Original:**

I'm trying to share files from one Mac and access them on a different Mac in the same network, while connecting as *Guest*. But the other Mac always gets "**Connection Failed**" no matter what I try.

If I try "Connect to Server" in Finder and use the smb address (e.g. `smb://192.168.0.135`), I get a more detailed error: "**There are no shares available or you are not allowed to access them on the server.**".

[image: Ventura File Sharing as Guest error]

I tried it from and to macOS Ventura 13.2, Monterey and Big Sur. Same thing every time.

As far as configuration goes, I have:

- In Settings - Users & Groups I have Guest User set to "Sharing Only"
- In Settings - General - Sharing, the shares have "Allow guest access" checked

[image: File Sharing On macOS Ventura 13.2]

I tried the suggestion from [Mounting SMB share on Monterey is rejected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441203/mounting-smb-share-on-monterey-is-rejected/454399) and this [Apple Technote](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT210659), but when I run in Terminal:

```
# dscl /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1 -read /config/dirserv apple-enabled-auth-mech
Data source (/LDAPv3/127.0.0.1) is not valid.
```

I spent hours with Apple on the phone trying to debug this, without any luck. I also tried to connect using the other Mac's admin user which connects and I can see the shares (and the entire HD since it's the local admin user), but that is also not very stable since a recent Ventura release. After a while, browsing the shared files, Finder locks up and starts spinning forever. However, I would like to get Guest access to work, most importantly.

Anyone else experiencing this problem?

Comment: What folder are you trying to share and what are the permissions on that folder?

Comment: I updated the question to include a File Sharing screenshot that shows the folders and their permissions. The folder I am trying to share is a custom folder in the Documents folder path.

Comment: What if you disable the builtin guest account and manually create an account with no admin privileges?

Comment: I have already tried connecting with the admin account, and that causes Finder to stop responding, as many people describe in the [AppleInsider's post comments](https://forums.appleinsider.com/discussion/230654#first-reply).

Comment: If thats, the case I would avoid SMB direct connection between two Macs and try with either a shared volume on a NAS or Windows/Linux box or just create a shared folder in the cloud.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But this involves complicated setup for something as simple as File Sharing that should work, especially between two Macs and the same operating system. It appears to be a bug in Ventura and it doesn't look like there's any fix until Apple fixes it in a future update.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but SMB file sharing on macOS has been a sore spot for years. I use a Synology NAS at home and solved the issues Apple seems to create for themselves.